# Differentiate between bad path and cancelled input in Excel.Workbook.SaveAs()

Tags: office-interop, excel-interop

In my app, I programmatically create an Excel file and then save to a predetermined path. In one (possibly common) instance, the file may already exist and SaveAs() pops up a dialog, asking if the user wants to overwrite or cancel.  Another (less likely, but actually just happened) option is that the directory to which the file usually gets saved DNE. Cancelling the "Overwrite?" dialog and the bad pathname both raise a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` exception with `ErrorCode`== 0x800a03ec.  I would like to differentiate between the two scenarios so I can just cancel silently, or give the user another chance to save the file elsewhere, respectively. I can't see any other info in the exception that would give me more info. Is there somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up testing for the file's existence, and if it wasn't there, then I throw up a `SaveFileDialog` window to let the user choose a valid place.